# How to limit any devices to appear on any Bonjour/Airplay capable devices close by?

Tags: security, appletv, airplay, bonjour, dns

This is an issue at my school district where I work as a network admin. Right now, I could see around the list of at least 15-20 Apple TVs that is located across school buildings when I press on AirPlay function on my iPhone 6. Our only security we have is right now that all Apple TVs require password to access before we can use them.

What is a good method to limit Apple TVs to only ones that teachers should be seeing in the list to select from? I am trying to find the answer for this on Internet but I cannot find one.

Comment: What does your infrastructure look like, at a first glance some isolated vlans or SSID's for devices would probably work.

Comment: Since the Apple TV are seen on an iPhone, the information leak is going through wireless network, the WLAN. It is rather difficult to fix any firewall on… space. The leak should be controlled at the source level: Apple TV & `5353/udp`.

Comment: I changed `ios` tag for a `security` one, because I'm sure the culprit isn't the one who see the problem (here `ios`). The one who see the problem is my friend :).

Comment: Daniel, thanks for changing the tag to security which makes more sense.

Comment: tron_jones, each school building have layer 2 switches with several vlans and all of them connect to a pair of core layer 3 switches.  

Hosts within most vlans can communicate with each other via both core switches.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on your network setup.

You could as @tron_jones suggested use isolated networks or VLANs. Another way would be to setup the router so that each class room is on a different subnet i.e.

10.0.1.0/24 for class room 1
10.0.2.0/24 for class room 2
10.0.3.0/24 for class room 3

mDNS / Bonjour does not broadcast outside of the subnet by default.

Either of these options should work, but require a non-trivial amount of alteration to your LAN, essentially there is no solution within the product itself.